# Hierarchical DropDownList in Asp.net MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select, hierarchical

How can I create a hierarchical dropdownlist in MVC Razor?

I've tried to make it as per the following code. I've searched for a solution but I haven't found one. I'd be grateful for any help.

```
@model IEnumerable<Sample.Models.Category>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<select>
    @HierarchicalDropDownList(Model, 0)
</select>

@helper HierarchicalDropDownList(IEnumerable<Sample.Models.Category> model, int? parent)
{
    if (model.Any(n => n.ParentId == parent))
    {
        string padding = "";
        foreach (var m in model)
        {
            padding += "-";
            <option value="@padding @m.CategoryId">@m.Title</option>
            HierarchicalDropDownList(model, m.CategoryId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to indent you option labels inside that drop down list ?

Comment: Yes i want only indent in front of the category title such as list menu.